# Safelink issue with Edge Browser in iOS App – Opening Appstore Instead of App

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, safelinks

The issues we are currently experiencing with the SafeLink policy.
Our organization utilizes the SafeLink policy, and we have observed that the deep link functions seamlessly across browsers when SafeLink is not applied. However, upon adding SafeLink to the URL, the deep link functionality is restricted to Safari only.

I have provided both the SafeLink and non-SafeLink URLs for your reference:

SafeLink URL:
[https://nam12.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2F<SITELINK (Eg.xxx.yyy.com)>.%2FteamDay%3FteamDayId%3DHTWmmt7cmYyd7LawwhMq5%2BMyNt%2Bf8eUCz25pzmsTUMo%3D%26domainUrl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fxxx.dev.com&data=05%7C02%7C%40%7Cb6ffab414d034bbceb0108dbfd382f0c%7C454af8f364734bce8aa5f9403e1d1271%7C0%7C0%7C638382189984623308%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=B5rzVQ0alWjIsT7ycI2oZrNjeVPM%2BeoMk0YDpMZk6q4%3D&reserved=0]

Non-SafeLink URL:
[https://xxx.yyysoftware.com/teamDay?teamDayId=p0RQIAsd4vaTk1yHGuTUdBCDmP0ZK1CuR8Q3JfSPJvU=&domainUrl=https://xxx.dev.com]

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.